# Download the references of an IEEE paper in latex style

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

Let's say I want to use many references of a single IEEE paper. Is there a way to download the .bib file for all the referencesences from IEEE website? I see I can download one specific paper's citation, but not many at the same time.

Comment: @Welcome to TeX.SE. You meant a .bib file (not the latex source files) for all the references, right?

Comment: Yes, just the .bib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends of "where" in the IEEE Explorer sites you are.

You may download as many as you can in the "search results" area.

[image]

After clicking on Export button a new Tab will open and you may select all (Ctrl + A) and Copy (Ctrl + C) them all into your `.bib` file.

[image]

I strongly recommend you to revise the automated generated data, the citation's key and other infos you might want in your references.

When you are in a specific paper, as far as I know, you can download only citation of that paper.

[image]

Once again, after copying it, it is up to you to organize and check all automated generated data.